# Problems with performance of drawing image

Tags: python, graphics

I used matplotlib and pyqtgraph to draw image containing several millions of pixels (there were no big area with same color), but they were pretty slow. How can one improve performance? I don't even need to show it on screen, only save to file. I use Windows.

Comment: too broad as you have no specifics in your question. What code you use to render there are a lot of apis ... what does it mean slow and for what resolution as sometimes 10 ms is fast another time slow ...  please add what you can to narrow your problem down to something answerable otherwise an adequate answer to this whould be some full tutorial on 2D gfx in python which will never fit into 30KB limit ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up using PyOpenCV.